# Jquery isotope flicker at chrome and opera not at firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-isotope

[Here](http://www.perfect-contour.com/dev/products/category/all) is the online demo, if you open this page at chrome, you can click the gray menu bar "All" "machine"..., when click more, you can see the problem, when click the after two times, the whole page will flicker after click.

It is well at firefox and IE, but has same problem at chrome and opera, safari is also and worst.

Can someone give me some tips to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `animationEngine: 'jquery'`. It doesn't look as good as css transitions, but the flicker goes away.

Reference: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html

Another solution: set `transformsEnabled: false`.

Reference for that one: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#css-transforms

Comment: Thanks! I will have a try.